# Change reload interval to waiting after the last reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

My application reloads data every 500ms. How do I have to change the code to not reload every 500ms but to wait for 500ms after the last reload to trigger a new one?

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    var switchboard = App.Switchboard.find(switchboard_id);
    setInterval(function() {
      switchboard.reload();
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just done something similar. You should use `activate` property on your route (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_activate).

Checkout this pull request: https://github.com/chrmod/rowmark/pull/2/files

#### Some example:

```
App.NoteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      this.get('controller').set('toSave', true);
    }.bind(this), 5000);
  }
})
```

#### UPDATE

I understand you wrong. Sorry for that.

First of all you need to know that `find` from `Ember Model` or `Ember Data` returns `promises` (http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html)

I think you can do such trick to implement that:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    var switchboard;
    setInterval(function() {
      switchboard = App.Switchboard.find(switchboard_id).then(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){}, 499);
      });
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

First of all we run `setInterval` to run this in infinity `loop`. Next in each loop iteration we find `Switchboard` and when `Ember data` loads from external server those data that run `function` that is passed to `then`. This function simply wait 499ms :)

Comment: Would you mind to add a bit more description? I don't understand how this solves my problem.

Comment: @wintermeyer Hi I have just updated my answer, maybe this is what you need :)